# To know port numbers in openvswitch

Tags: sdn, mininet, openvswitch, ryu

I am running a switch test [Switch Test](https://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/html/switch_test_tool.html) on real environment with one openvswitch and real sdn switch.

I created a bridge on openvswitch and added ports (ex. eth0, eht1). But I want to know logical port numbers (like 1, 2) which command gives me correct information. `ovs-ofctl show bridge s1` shows

```
1(eth3): mac address etc
2(eth4):
5(eth5):
```

and `ovs-dpctl show`

```
port 2: eth3
port 3: eth4
port 4: eth5
```

But results are not showing proper mapping of physical to logical ports. Observer `eth5` in both cases for `ofctl` it gives 5 and for `dpctl` it gives 4. Is there any way to get correct port id's.

I personally feel both these commands are not giving correct port ids. To isolate this scenario. On Mininet I created 2 openvswitchs and run `dpctl` command as above it gives me 1,2,3,4,5,6 as port numbers but I am not able to run the test with these port numbers. For both switches  I used 1,2,3 test executes successfully. What I mean it, if I give 1,2,3 port numbers for one switch and 4,5,6 for another switch tests doesn't execute. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I found the way to debug. used https://github.com/Ehsan70/RyuApps/blob/master/TopoDiscoveryInRyu.md code to get exact topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command to specify the ofport of the port you are adding in the bridge:

```
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth0 -- set Interface eth0 ofport=1
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use to show ofport

```
sudo ovs-vsctl -- --columns=name,ofport list Interface
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. The question is how to know port number, not how to crate with secific port number. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i think you can try ovs-vsctl list Interface

Comment: `sudo ovs-vsctl list interface | grep 'name\|ofport' | grep -v 'status\|ofport_request'`

Answer (score 1):

I like this command to show me a clear picture of port numbers in OVS. For each interface, it shows ofport/dpport. Most of the time, you want to pay attention to ofport.

```
sudo ovs-appctl dpif/show
```

The ofport is the open flow port number and dpport is the port number in the underlying datapath (e.g. kernel, dpdk). Some interfaces, such as patch ports, do not have a datapath port number because they are optimized out of the real datapath.

Answer (score 0):

in mininet:

```
for switch in self.mySwitches:
        print('switch ports  :',switch.ports)
             for value in switch.ports.values():
                 print(value)
```

in ryu:

```
for value in datapath.ports.values():
    print(value.port_no)
```

I hope it is helpful